# VMFS 3.31 vs VMFS 3.33

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

After an upgrade of vmware 4.0 to 4.1, we now see 2 different versions of the vmfs LUNS.
Is there anyone that can tell me what the diffence is between ver. 3.31 and 3.33. And is it necessary to upgrade the volumes?

thx

Answer (score 2):

I've yet to find any concrete information regarding 3.33 but all indications point to minor bug fixes that aren't worth worrying about, there's also no 'one-click' way of upgrading them, adding weight to the 'don't bother' argument.

That said 4.1u1 seems to be creating new datastores in VMFS version 3.46 for what it's worth.

Answer (score 2):

3.33 added *optimistic IO*, but it's not worth recreating your datastores.

3.46 added some VAAI stuff, but unless you are using storage offloading on your SAN, that is not worth the upgrade either.

Here's [the VMFS KB](http://kb.vmware.com/kb/1005325).